# Probable bug in Export(String) and "String" format

Tags: bugs, export, string-manipulation

**Bug introduced in 6.0 and persisting through 11.0.0 or later**

---

```
ExportString[FullForm@f["String"], "String"]
ExportString[FullForm@f["string"], "String"]
(*==>*)
"f[\"\"]" 
"f[\"string\"]"
```

I would expect

```
"f[\"String\"]" 
"f[\"string\"]"
```

Obviously the string `"String"` receives some weird special treatment, but only if written verbatim with initial uppercase letter.

Confirmation?

Comment: Yes, it is somehow getting replaced: `TracePrint[ExportString["String", "String"], _ReplaceAll]`. I have filed a bug report.

Comment: @ilian Nice find. How did you know `ExportString` was implemented (partially?) in WL? Guess? Is all of the Import/Export stuff Wolfram Language code?

Comment: same confirmed w/10.1  ( and same for regular `Export` to a file )

Comment: Yes, a lot of the import/export code is implemented in top-level, though some of the functionality may call into the kernel or MathLink or LibraryLink libraries.

Comment: I confirm the bug with versions 8.0.4 and 11.0.0. In version 5.2 the bug isn't present.